# How can I dynamically add plane meshes to an object

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I want to sculpt terrain for an open world game that I am working on and I'm looking for a way to have blender dynamically add plane meshes for me to sculpt as I work, kind of like a minecraft-ish chunk system almost, rather than creating one massive plane mesh and trying to navigate it.
Are there any addons/extensions that can accomplish this or something similar?
And if not, what are the techniques one might use to sculpt a large open-world terrain?

Comment: I'm hesitant to respond to this because I don't have a good solution for Blender. With that said, I just did this for the first time a few weeks ago. After going through the whole process of sculpting in Blender, exporting my map, then importing it to UE5, I can confidently say that I wish I would have just sculpted the map natively in Unreal. After all, that's exactly what game engines are made for. You'll have to manually smooth out your terrain in whatever engine you import the height map too anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I agree that if I were just limiting myself to heightmaps the better way would absolutely be game engine sculpting. The problem I have with it is that to my knowledge UE5 terrain sclupting is limited to heightmaps and I want to be able to introduce caves and arches to my terrain, which isn't doable with purely heightmaps